# JVMVRFY013:Runtime error found at server start up with JVM 1.8

Tags: java, xml, dom, java-8, linkageerror

I am using `wstx-asl.jar` for xml parsing, recently we have upgrated java version from 1.7 to 1.8 after upgrade we are getting runtime error in server start up.

> Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.naming.CannotInstantiateObjectException: Exception occurred while the JNDI NamingManager was processing a javax.naming.Reference object. [Root exception is java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=com/ctc/wstx/sr/BasicStreamReader, method=getNamespaceContext()Ljavax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext;, pc=0]

But if we build EAR with JVM 1.7 this error is not appearing,
only if we build EAR with JVM 1.8 we are getting this error.

Is there any dependency with java version and the ant build sequence?

Initial checking on the issue showed that this error is due to parsing the **hbm config file** with non JAXB jar,

Also as a resolution part I have removed the **wstx-asl.jar** and built, and it is not having any issues in JVM 1.8.

My question is if I need to use **wstx-asl.jar** do I need to change any thing in build sequence while using JVM 1.8?

--
Thanks